# Outlook Add-in Event On-open email

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I've been trying to activate my add-in when the user open his email so I can analyze it. I found one example in on add-in from another company ([Retruster](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7Mrb1A87Rg)). The issue I didn't found way to reproduce the action. Someone knows how to reproduce this event? Because I just found when sending a message.

Answer (score 1):

The labels shown on the YouTube video are categories set on emails. They can be set on the Exchange server side when your message arrives without any add-in involved. Remember, add-in activation rules are described in the manifest file - it can be regex filters, known entities etc. Read more about them in the [Activation rules for contextual Outlook add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/activation-rules)  article.

The add-in starts working when the user clicks on the ribbon button.

Comment: Okay, I gonna take look. Thank you!